# Adding multiple sites at once to forward-zone of Unbound?

Tags: dns

The usual format for Unbound forward-zone is

```
forward-zone:
name: "imap.gmail.com"
forward-addr: 8.8.8.8 #googleDNS
forward-addr: 8.8.4.4 #googleDNS
```

for example. Is it possible to add multiple sites in a list to the `name' field? I've tried comma separation but doesn't seem to work, e.g. something perhaps like:

```
forward-zone:
name: "site1.com; site2.com"
forward-addr: 8.8.8.8 #googleDNS
forward-addr: 8.8.4.4 #googleDNS
```

perhaps? If so what is the correct format for the list of sites? I just want to save some space in the `unbound.conf' file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you want to have multiple forward zones, you have to define each one individually, no matter whether the forwarders are the same or not for each one of them.

Comment: That's a bummer in my case, where I want a "split-DNS-forward" functionality with multiple DNS forwarders.